# Using cout to print the entire contents of a character array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am quite new to C++ (just a shaky background in Java) and I'm stumped about how to print out the entire contents of a char array. I believe I need to use a loop, and base the loop on the length of the array, but my attempts to compile aren't meeting with success. This is what I have right now. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void namePrinting(char name[])
{
   int i = 0;
   cout << "Name: ";
   while(i <= name.length() )
   {
   cout << name[i];
   i++;
   }

}

int main()
{
   string fullName;
   cout << "Enter name: ";
   cin >> fullName;
   char nameArray[fullName.length()];
   namePrinting(nameArray);
}
```

Comment: Just print the `std::string`.

Comment: The assignment requires me to use a char array, unfortunately.

Comment: What assignment ? Just use `cout<<fullName;`

Comment: An array of char used as a string will (normally) be NUL-terminated. ostream has an overload of `operator<<` to print out a complete NUL-terminated string.

Comment: `char nameArray[fullName.length()];` it is not legal. The length of the array should be known at compile time. You need to allocate dynamically your array (using `new`)

Comment: Using an actual array (not a pointer) when you already have a `std::string` is impossible due to the compile-time constant requirement. Being that a pointer can be used, then, doing `std::cout << fullName.c_str();` should technically fulfill the assignment requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to just accept the input (first and last name, with a space) into a char array and bypass the string altogether?

Comment: Sure, `char name[128]; cin.getline(char, 128);`  Though by using a character array you have a predefined fixed length (in this case 128).

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, Chad. As I learn more I'll be able to make it more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to print an array of, say, `int`? An array of `char` is not the best place to start, since it has some idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I do not. I read about the problem of not having a null terminator but that doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Answer (score 31):

Start with something simple:

```
char c_array[3];
c_array[0] = 'a';
c_array[1] = 'b';
c_array[2] = 'c';

for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i)
{
  cout << c_array[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

**Do not go farther until you understand that much perfectly.** Now notice that if you null-terminate the array, you can pass the whole thing to `cout`, and `operator<<` will know when to stop:

```
char c_array[4];
c_array[0] = 'a';
c_array[1] = 'b';
c_array[2] = 'c';
c_array[3] = 0;

cout << c_array << endl;
```

*You cannot do that with arrays of most other types.* Now notice that you can assign a `char[]` this way, and it will be null-terminated:

```
char c_array[20] = "abc";
cout << c_array << endl;
```

You can even omit the size of the array, and the compiler will infer it:

```
char c_array[] = "abc";    // this is a char[4];
cout << c_array << endl;
```

There are a couple of different ways to read user input into an array, but it sounds as if you know that already, and this answer is getting long.

Answer (score 4):

Writing each character individually using `operator<<(char)` is inefficient.

Converting to an `std::string` using the `(const char*, size_t)` constructor, and writing that using `operator<<(const std::string&)` is also inefficient.

The proper way is simply to use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

PS: Note that your code is not valid C++. `char name[]` is basically synonymous with `char* name` and doesn't know its length (and there's no `.length()` on it too). And your `nameArray` is not initialized. Sized, yes; initialized, no. You're missing a `std::copy` or `strncpy` call to copy the content of `fullName` into `nameArray`.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%s", nameArray);
```

just works!

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, my program was looking for a command line parameter. Since I did not provide the parameter, so it throws terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::logic_error what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid`

I hope this gives you some insight on how to figure your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way to do it.

[Run example](http://cpp.sh/8kghf)

```
// write out any c style char array to an output stream
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

void write_char_array(std::ostream& os, const char* string) {
    // faster than an ostream_iterator and std::copy
    os.write(string, strlen(string));
}

int main()
{
    const char question[] = "What is your name? ";
    const char* answer    = "Bob";

    write_char_array(std::cout, question);
    write_char_array(std::cout, answer);
}
```

Output:

```
What is your name? Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit <O/T> from the OP, but I googled "c++ print `std::array` char" and this was the top hit, yet none of these answers cover how to do this with `std::array<char, >`.  You can't apply the `operator<<` directly to the array, you need to access its `.data()` pointer first:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
 
int main()
{
  // a direct initialization example. Remember, need string legnth+1 for
  // a NUL terminator
  std::array<char, 6> bar{"hello"};
  // print to std::out using operator<< and the .data() ptr access
  std::cout << bar.data() << std::endl;

  // extra example copying the contents of a string to an array.
  std::string foo("how are you?");
  // {} initializes it to 0, giving us guaranteed NUL termination
  std::array<char, 24> tar{};
  // copy string to array, std::min ensures we won't overrun
  foo.copy(tar.data(), std::min(foo.length(), tar.size()-1));
  std::cout << tar.data() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
how are you?
```

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/dGGq8Yn7e)